extracting the instances of numeric value in dataframe
In each of the dataframe, I have a row entry that looks like:
[{'degree': 0.1, 'name': 'Colins Dental Clinic', 'rating': 9, 'level': 'fourth'}]

It is a direct import from read.csv of a file.
I would like to create two columns from each entry that extracts two numeric values, from above, 0.1, and 9, which are degree and rating information of a dental clinic.
I tried substring and using sep="," with quotes, but I am just not getting things correctly.
How do I do it correctly?

It looks like JSON data not correctly formated (because of the single quotes).
You didn't provide a sample of your dataframe but you can try something like this (2 options) :
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

### Data
df=data.frame(col1="dummy",
              col2="dummy",
              col3="[{'degree': 0.1, 'name': 'Colins Dental Clinic', 'rating': 9, 'level': 'fourth'}]")

### Option 1 : Transform your column data into a valid JSON then extract data from it
df1=df %>% mutate(col3=str_replace_all(col3,"'","\\\""),
                  col3=str_replace_all(col3,"(?<=: )None(?=[,}])","\\\"None\\\""),
                  degree=fromJSON(col3)$degree,
                  rating=fromJSON(col3)$rating)

### Option 2 : Use regex to get directly what you need (less secure)
df2=df %>% mutate(degree=str_extract(col3,"(?<=degree': )\\d\\.\\d"),
                 rating=str_extract(col3,"(?<=rating': )\\d"))

Output :


I am getting this error message:  lexical error: invalid char in json text. I have a field that has something like: 'Parking Lot': None. None is where the error occurs. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer has been updated with a fix to manage "None" cases. You could otherwise use "Option 2".

Hey, thanks for the update. In your option 2 method, I am getting the error messsage:
Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Option 2 is valid to me. Please check your dataframe name ("df" or another name), the column name which contains JSON data ("col3" or another name) and the presence of the pipe operator :%>%.

It does work! You were right, my df name was incorrect! Thanks a lot!
